# How to copy my Java Eclipse project to desktop, and then run with the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have built a java program using Eclipse. Now my teacher wants all separate java files in one folder, and then the teacher will run my program through command line. I've tried copying the java files over to my desktop and running through command line, I get errors.

My program also has two packages as well in it. Anyone know how to fix this? without using any plugins or something, as my teacher will not have them.

Edit: I managed to fix it, it was because of my classpath had wrong directory

Comment: why copy it to desktop , just give the path in console to the directory where your project is and run the main class file , remember the call the class file not the .java file

Comment: my <package> does not exist, Im copying it to a folder on the desktop. So I can hand in this folder to my teacher

Comment: @Hussain Akhtar Wahid  Thanks I will try that now.

Answer (score 4):

Just export your project in an runnable jar file, then go in cmd and execute: 
java -jar .jar

Comment: Thanks for that, but my teacher wanted a folder with the java files. I've managed to do it. Thanks though!

Comment: Next time, write how you solved it.